# Is there anyway to combine StandardSetController and List

Tags: visualforce, custom-controller, table, pagination

I need to be able to edit and save records in a pagination. Right now I can get the pagination to work if i have apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Accounts}" but then i can't refresh the page with a different picklist selection or search accounts. Alternatively if i set apex:pageBlockTable value="{!RecordList}" i can search accounts and switch accounts with the dropdown menu but pagination doesn't work.

*********************************************SOLVED*******************************************************

UPDATED CODE BELOW

APEX

```
public class AccountTypeController 
{
    //declare variables

    public Account filterAccount{get; set;}
     List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    //search
    public String searchString { get; set; }
    public Account[] accs{ get; set; }
    //Return table
    public Account[] recordList{get; set;}
    public Account[] updateList{get; set;}
    //Pagination
    public Integer noOfRecords{get; set;}
    public Integer pageSize{get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> paginationSizeOptions{get;set;}
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {get; set;}


    //constructor
    public AccountTypeController()
    {
        //initialize variables
        filterAccount = new Account();
        recordList = new List<Account>();
        pageSize=20;
        Database.QueryLocator qLoc;

        //initialize set controller using a SOQL query:
        qLoc = Database.getQueryLocator([Select Name, Type, Website, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry  
                    from Account where type =:filterAccount.type Order by Name ASC Limit 10000]);
        setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(qLoc);

        paginationSizeOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        paginationSizeOptions.add(new SelectOption('5','5'));
        paginationSizeOptions.add(new SelectOption('10','10'));
        paginationSizeOptions.add(new SelectOption('20','20'));
        paginationSizeOptions.add(new SelectOption('50','50'));
        paginationSizeOptions.add(new SelectOption('100','100'));

    }

   public void doSearch() {
        String soqlQuery = 'SELECT id, Name, type, website, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState,'+ 
                    'BillingPostalcode, BillingCountry FROM Account';
        String tempTerm;
        if(String.isNotBlank(searchString)) {
            tempTerm = '%'+searchString+'%';
            soqlQuery += ' WHERE Name LIKE :tempTerm';
        }
        recordList = Database.query(soqlQuery);
   }

    //saving records
    public pageReference save()
    {
        try
        {
            update recordList;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.debug('Exception occurred ' + String.valueOf(e));

        }    
        return null;
    }



    // Initialize setCon and return a list of record    

    public List<Account> getAccounts() 
    {
                return (List<Account>) setCon.getRecords();
    }

       //fields returning for table
  public void updateRecordList()
    {
        setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([Select Name, Type, Website, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry  
                    from Account where type =:filterAccount.type Order by Name ASC Limit 10000]));
    }



     //Changes the size of pagination
    public PageReference refreshPageSize() {
         setCon.setPageSize(pageSize);
         return null;
    }

     public Integer resultSize
    {
        get{
                return noOfRecords;
        }
        set;
    }

    public Integer pageNumber {
        get {
            return setCon.getPageNumber();
        }
        set;
    }

    public pageReference setpageSize()
    {
      setCon.setPageSize(PageSize);
        return null;
    }

        public void first() {
        setCon.first();
    }

    public void last() {
        setCon.last();
    } 
    public void previous() {
        setCon.previous();
    }

    public void next() {
        setCon.next();
    }



}
```

VF

```
<apex:page controller="AccountTypeController" sidebar="false">

    <apex:form ><br/><br/>

    <!---Accounts by Type title-->
      <div style="text-align:center; font-size:30px;">
        <apex:outputText value="Accounts By Type"/>
      </div>

      <apex:actionFunction name="refreshPageSize" action="{!refreshPageSize}" status="fetchStatus" rerender="account_filter"/>   

        <apex:outputPanel style="display: block" id="pwPanel">

          <apex:pageBlock >

                <apex:inputText value="{!SearchString}" id="theSearchString" maxLength="100" size="30"/>
                 <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!doSearch}" rerender="pwPanel"/>
               <br/>

               <apex:inputfield value="{!filterAccount.Type}" label="Account Type"> 
                 <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!updateRecordList}" rerender="pwPanel"/>                  
               </apex:inputfield>

   <br/><br/><br/>


            <!-----------Table---------->                  

               <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!Accounts.size > 0}" id="account_filter">

                   <apex:pageBlockSection >


                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Accounts}" var="rl" id="record_list">

                       <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton"
                                               hideOnEdit="editButton" event="onclick"/>

                            <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" value="{!rl.Name}">           
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column headerValue="Type">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!rl.Type}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column headerValue="Website">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!rl.Website}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column headerValue="Billing Street">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!rl.BillingStreet}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column headerValue="Billing City">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!rl.BillingCity}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column headerValue="Billing State">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!rl.BillingState}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column headerValue="Billing Zip/Postal Code">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!rl.BillingPostalCode}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column headerValue="Billing Country">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!rl.BillingCountry}" />
                            </apex:column>

                    </apex:pageBlockTable> 

                   <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" id="SaveButton" value="Save"/>
                   </apex:pageBlockSection>



<!-----------First, Previous, Next, Last Command Buttons---------->                      

                <apex:panelGrid columns="8"> 

                <apex:selectList value="{!pagesize}" multiselect="false" size="1" onchange="refreshPageSize();">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!paginationSizeOptions}"/>
                </apex:selectList>


                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="account_filter" value="First" action="{!setCon.first}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasPrevious}" title="First Page"/> 

                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="account_filter" value="Previous" action="{!setCon.previous}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasPrevious}" title="Previous Page"/> 

                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="account_filter" value="Next" action="{!setCon.next}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" title="Next Page"/> 

                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="account_filter" value="Last" action="{!setCon.last}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" title="Last Page"/> 


                <apex:outputPanel >                      
                    <apex:actionStatus id="fetchStatus" >
                        <apex:facet name="start" >
                          <img src="/img/loading.gif" />                    
                        </apex:facet>
                    </apex:actionStatus>
                </apex:outputPanel> 

            </apex:panelGrid> 



<!---------------------------------------------------->

                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlock>  

         </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: you should check out this [blog post](http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/pagination-using-standard-set-controller-salesforce/) for an elegant way to do standardsetcontrollers that uses less code than you have. Note how the pagesize is done via onChange event on the selectList

Comment: That really cleaned up a lot of the code but pageSize still isn't working correctly nor is the next,previous,last,first. It still only displays one page.

Comment: i literally just implemented the code in http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/pagination-using-standard-set-controller-salesforce/ and it worked perfectly first time

Comment: Yeah maybe the code in the blog because its not doing as much as mine. Mine works until you try to select a different picklist option and then it wont update. I need to be able to edit and save the records.

Answer (score 2):

Visualforce does not automatically rerender changed attributes. To reflect changed attributes, you need to `rerender` the `outputpanel` inside which you know there are changes or else use `getters`.

You should be using below in apex code:

```
public List<Opportunity> getRecordlist() {
     return (List<Account>) setCon.getRecords();
}
```

This is a getter which will update the records when you use `RecordsList` as value in table.

Also use outputpanel around table and rerender that:

```
<apex:commandButton reRender="pwPanel" value="Next" action="{!setCon.next}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" title="Next Page"/>
```

Also move `pwPanel` just around table or else `inputField` will also get rerendered which is not needed.

**Good practices:**

StandardSetController already has methods like `getHasNext()` and `next()` or `last()`. You dont need to implement these methods in apex. Lot of visualforce developers are unaware of this.

Refer: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_methods.htm

example:

```
<apex:commandButton reRender="tabelPanel" value="Last" action="{!setCon.last}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" title="Last Page"/>
```

**--- added ----**

Also updateRecordList is just assigning to recordList but not returning set controller. you can remove `updateRecordList` and You need to implement:

```
public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
    get {
        if(setCon == null) {                
            setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                  [Select Name, Type, Website, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, 
                BillingPostalcode, BillingCountry 
                From Account Where Type = :filterAccount.Type
                Limit 10000]));
            setCon.setPageSize(size);  
            noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();
        }            
        return setCon;
    }
    set;
}
```

**----added-----**

```
public ApexPages.StandardSetController setcon {
    get{
        if(setCon == null){
            setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(recordsList()));
            setCon.setpageSize(pageSize);
            noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();
        }
        return setCon;
    }set;
}

void recordsList(){
    return [Select Name, Type, Website, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry  
                from Account where type =:filterAccount.type Order by Name ASC Limit 10000];
}

public void updateRecordList()
{
    setcon=null;
}
```

Comment: added answer...

Comment: Im using updaterecordlist to be able to save the records after editing. I also already have that code implemented.

Comment: Pls mark as solved if solved

Comment: you doing rerender of pwPanel there

Comment: you can actually use refreshPageSize() for onchange so that it rerenders page block

Comment: posted new code. If i get rid of updateRecordList and i change the (apex:actionsupport action="getAccounts"> i get the Visualforce arraylist error saying action method must be pagereference. Which doesn't make sense because the updateRecordList method is of void type.

Comment: In updateRecordList you have to update setcon. Only then your records in UI will change as it's referring to setcon

Comment: How would you update an apexpage standardSetController inside an Account method? Im getting the illegal assignment error anywhere i try to put it.

Comment: do you really need a separate method for recordList? why did you do it that way vs putting the SOQL query inside the queryLocator?